# Where is Yuma Kuga’s mother?

Tags: world-trigger

If you think about it, we all know what Yuma’s father, Yugo, looks like and what happened to him, but the manga and anime never seems to mention Yuma’s mother. Whatever happened to her? Is she dead, did she and Yugo have a divorce, or what? Because there had to be a relationship with a woman if Yuma is Yugo’s son. (Or is Yuma adopted?)

Answer (score 2):

As of current writing, **Yuma's mother has never been mentioned ever** in the story, and not even in any interviews/Q&A sessions. (Otherwise, information about her *in Japanese* should come as popular/surprising, but *I found none* and only the same questions in Japanese with fan theories about her being a Neighbor or not, etc.).

Thus, it's also impossible to answer any questions related to her: whatever happened to her, is she dead or divorced, etc.

There are some fan theories if Yuma was adopted, but that's just fan theories.

Comment: As for the reason, the following question [Why do anime mothers often get the short end of the stick?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/49006) might be of interest (but may also be biased), or it could just be that she is not important to advance the story (a mantra for writers).