# Why was Itsuki about to eat alone in the 1st episode?

Tags: the-quintessential-quintuplets

In the 1st episode/the pilot/premiere, we see that Itsuki was about to eat alone when Fuutaro 1st meets Itsuki. The next day (same episode), Itsuki eats with the other quints. Why didn't Itsuki eat with the other quints previously? Where were the other quints anyway?

- **Note**: It goes the same in the 1st chapter of the manga.

See here:

1. Itsuki is about to eat alone, but then Fuutarou comes.

[image]

2. The next day, Itsuki eats with the other quints.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From reddit [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/5ToubunNoHanayome/comments/uc1pcf/why_was_itsuki_about_to_eat_alone_in_the_1st/) and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/ItsukiClassroom/comments/uc1pec/why_was_itsuki_about_to_eat_alone_in_the_1st/), there appears to be no in-universe reason, but there may be an in-universe explanation for an out-universe reason.

The out-universe reason is based on something from Itsuki or Yotsuba's character books (from user Cave_TP) :

> Because the scene was added later, Negi's original idea was to have Yotsuba as the first to meet Fuutarou.
>
> The publisher told Negi to have Itsuki as the first one because a genki characters wouldn't have been the ideal as the "main girl" due to how the story is built so this scene got added later.

An in-universe explanation which talks about S01E04 too (from user Tusk_Act_IV) :

> It's actually possible that only Itsuki bothered going to school that day to fill in their paperwork. Maruo did seem to rely on her for such things like with Fuutarou's pay.