# When did 'onii-chan' start to become a fan service stuff?

Tags: anime-history

'Onii-chan' is just how a girl addresses her big bro originally. But now, it's widely used as a fan service in anime. When did 'onii-chan' start to become a fan service stuff?

Comment: 1 - Maybe the same time '[imouto](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/49006/why-do-anime-mothers-often-get-the-short-end-of-the-stick/67494#67494)' became a popular trope in anime? 2 - how do boys address their older brothers in anime if not onii-chan too?

Comment: Don't have full answer but you can check this KnowYourMeme page to know when was this meme started: https://amp.knowyourmeme.com/memes/onii-chan

Comment: Has always been like that as far as I remember. Maybe it was different in the 1970s, but it has been like that since at least the 1980s. Of course, it depends on the anime.